# How to loop in ractive.js

Tags: ractivejs

I have got the following data (sample):

```
"data": {
        "eventsHeading": "Upcoming events",
        "eventsToBeDisplayed": 3,
        "allEventLinkText": "See all events",
        "eventsList": [
    {
        "eventDate": "22/12/2015",
        "eventTitle": "EVENT INFO 1"
    },
    {
        "eventDate": "22/12/2015",
        "eventTitle": "EVENT INFO 2"
    },
    {
        "eventDate": "14/01/2016",
        "eventTitle": "EVENT INFO 3"
    },
    {
        "eventDate": "14/01/2016",
        "eventTitle": "EVENT INFO 4"
    }
        ]
    }
```

And I have something like this:

```
{{#eventsList}}
    <tr>
        <td class="date-column">{{eventDate}}</td>
        <td class="text-link truncate-text"><span decorator="tooltip:{{eventTitle}}" tabindex="0">{{eventTitle}}</span>
    </tr>
{{/}}
```

And now it will just print all the data for `eventList`. What I want to do is add a `for` loop like

```
i=0;i<={{eventsToBeDisplayed}};i++
```

so only 3 of the data will show.

What do you think is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an [indexer to the loop](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/mustaches#array-index-references) and then conditionally filter inside the loop:

```
{{#eventsList:i}}
    {{# i < eventsToDisplay}}
    <tr>
        <td class="date-column">{{eventDate}}</td>
        <td class="text-link truncate-text"><span decorator="tooltip:{{eventTitle}}" tabindex="0">{{eventTitle}}</span>
    </tr>
    {{/}}
{{/}}
```

Comment: Hi @martypdx. Nice way of using array index reference. Works like a charm. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use computed properties - I like to do this because it seems a little more explicit than a loop where the entire body is wrapped in an if, you can reuse it more easily, you can do calculations or checks against that subset of data in other areas, etc...

template

```
{{#topEvents}}
    <tr>...</tr>
{{/}}
```

script (computed goes on same level as data)

```
computed: {
    topEvents: function(){
        return this.get('eventsToDisplay').slice(0, this.get('eventsToBeDisplayed'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @PersonThing, thank you also for this. Yes i believe this is more reusable. Ill keep in mind of this also.